# Install package on OS X using tlmgr

Tags: mactex, texpad, tlmgr

I'm using Texpad on OS X with MacTex backend. I need to install [biblatex-gost](https://github.com/odomanov/biblatex-gost/). The authors say that it can be installed automatically, though it doesn't happen. I added `\usepackage{biblatex-gost}` to my tex source and it couldn't find the package. I then ran `tlmgr install biblatex-gost`. It finished successfully, but Texpad still couldn't find the package. Now if I repeat `tlmgr install biblatex-gost`, it says

```
$ tlmgr install biblatex-gost
tlmgr: package repository http://ctan.altspu.ru/systems/texlive/tlnet (not verified: gnupg not available)
tlmgr install: package already present: biblatex-gost
```

Apparently, it is installed, so why can't Texpad find it? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you don't by chance have two latex installations and your texpad picks up the wrong one? Try compiling you document from the command line to test.

Comment: @daleif I'm sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`biblatex-gost` provides various styles for formatting your references with `biblatex`. As such its intended usage is via `biblatex`'s options. Here is one example taken from the [biblatex-gost documentation](http://texdoc.net/pkg/biblatex-gost):

```
\usepackage[%
    citestyle=alphabetic-verb,
    bibstyle=gost-alphabetic,
    ...
]{biblatex}
```